# Unable to resolve private dns zone over vpn with bind9 DNS

Tags: vpn, bind, internal-dns, ufw, wireguard

## The Problem

I have a VPC in which I need to access the servers using private FQDNs. The VPC is accessible through a wireguard VPN. The VPN server also serves as a DNS server running BIND9. I have set the DNS server with a private zone according to this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-18-04). From inside the VPC, the DNS works as expected and I am able to reach the servers by the FQDNs defined in the DNS zone.

When connecting to the VPC through the VPN tunnel, I am unable to resolve those FQDNs although I have setup my VPN client to use my private DNS server. I know the VPN client uses my private DNS server because when I run `nslookup google.com` I see my DNS's IP address as you can see the result below:

```
Server:     10.118.0.2
Address:    10.118.0.2#53
...
```

If I run the `nslookup myprivate.domain.com` from a machine connected to the VPC through the VPN tunnel, I receive a NXDOMAIN, the same goes for the `ping`, it fails with the error `Name or service not known`. However, if I run ping on the private IP address from the VPC, it works. So if `myprivate.domain.com` is hosted on on the server at`10.118.0.3`, the ping succeeds on the IP address but fails on the FQDN.

Additionally, see the dig results when inside the VPC vs when from a machine connected through the VPN:
`dig dev.myprivatedomain.com ns`:
FROM VPC:

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51703
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 9dccc02158dee7f70100000061a7e0a1ce2597e377b9c301 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dev.myprivatedomain.com.       IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
nabuinternal.com.   604800  IN  SOA ns1.myprivatedomain.com. ...

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.118.0.2#53(10.118.0.2)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 01 20:52:49 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 93
```

FROM VPN:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 57158
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dev.myprivatedomain.com.       IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            900 IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1638392201 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 44 msec
;; SERVER: 10.118.0.2#53(10.118.0.2)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 01 15:57:05 EST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

I notice that both use the same DNS server, but when requested from the VPN, the authority for my private domain is not returned.

**In conclusion**, after several hours of research, I'm falling short to find out what is missing for clients connecting to the VPC through the VPN to be able to resolve the FQDNs defined by my private DNS.

## Additional Information

- Server is ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Bind 9: `BIND 9.16.1-Ubuntu (Stable Release)`
- wireguard: `wireguard-tools v1.0.20200513` installed through wirespeed
- UFW enabled

The VPN and DNS server ip in the VPC is `10.118.0.2`.

The VPN address pool is `10.99.0.0/16` and I have set the BIND9 configurations in the following manner:

```
acl "trusted" {
    10.118.0.2;    # the vpn and dns server
    ...
    10.99.0.0/16;  # vpn address pool
    
};
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    listen-on { 10.118.0.0/20; 10.99.0.0/16; };  
    allow-transfer { none; };
    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
    };
};
```

The zone is configured this way:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.myprivatedomain.com. admin.myprivatedomain.com. (
                              9         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;                         
; name servers - NS records
    IN      NS      ns1.myprivatedomain.com.

; name servers - A records
ns1.myprivatedomain.com.          IN      A       10.118.0.2

; 10.118.0.0/20 - A records
dev.myprivatedomain.com.            IN      A      10.118.0.4
staging.myprivatedomain.com.         IN      A      10.118.0.3
```

and the reverse zone file:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.myprivatedomain.com. admin.myprivatedomain.com. (
                              7         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; name servers - NS records
    IN      NS      ns1.myprivatedomain.com.

; PTR Records
2.0   IN      PTR     ns1.myprivatedomain.com.         ; 10.118.0.2
4.0   IN      PTR     dev.myprivatedomain.com.         ; 10.118.0.4
3.0   IN      PTR     staging.myprivatedomain.com.      ; 10.118.0.3
```

UFW is set to allow port 53 for both TCP and UDP.

Also, UFW has before rules to allow traffic from the VPN:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.99.0.0/16 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

The previous rule was setup in order to allow a client to connect to the VPN tunnel and use the private DNS server. Without this rule, I am unable to access the internet unless I set the DNS address to a public one like google's one. I have found this rule during my research, however I am not yet very familiar with firewall configurations and I don't fully understand yet the implication of it. It has helped me get closer to my goal, but I need to do further reading on it.

Below is the wireguard VPN client config:

```
[Interface]
...
DNS = 10.118.0.2
Address = 10.99.0.2/16

[Peer]
...
AllowedIPs = 10.99.0.0/16, 10.118.0.0/20
```

## UPDATE: WORK AROUND

The wireguard server was installed through another software that packaged it and provided additional services (web interface, facilitated setup). The downside was that I had little control over the configuration of the wireguard server.

Consequently, I ended up removing the software and installing wireguard manually, which allowed me to properly setup the vpn, especially for the routing rules to work with my VPC setup. I needed to route the traffic in the VPN tunnel from the VPN interface to the VPC private interface instead of the public interface. This ended up solving my problem without having to modify the DNS server and zone configurations.

Comment: Your bind configuration shows only forwarders but no evidence that it is authoritative for your private (sub-)domain. Typically when you run a custom DNS  server you also need to configure one or more zones with your private (or public) DNS records

Comment: @Bob I have updated my post to include the zone and reverse zone files that configure my private subdomains.

Comment: listen-on is wrongly set, it shoall be the server ip or interface

Comment: Does anybody have a answer to this issue? I have the same problem with wireguard and bind9.

Comment: @simmeone I solved my problem by modifying the routing rules of my VPN. you can see my updated post. Hope this helps